# Features of JavaScript that C developers fail to take advantage of?

Tags: javascript, c, programming-languages

Fellow Stackers,

In the first Computer Science class I took, the professor used C++ as a teaching language.  He emphasized that the important things to understand are the concepts of programming, not just the language itself.

In the past few years, I've fallen in to a career in database driven web development.  At first, I was busy learning to use the server-side programming tools, namely ASP.net.  Most of my fellow co-workers from my early days didn't use much client-side scripting code, but I've been making a big effort to learn to write good client side scripting.

I've begun using jQuery in earnest.

The first thing that most any C++ or .net developer will notice about JavaScript upon first encountering it is that the syntax is remarkably similar to C-style languages.

There are important differences.  JavaScript uses variant data types, allows for arrays to be declared in-line, and uses it's own object syntax with curly braces.  Above all, JavaScript is an interpreted language that allows for a user to interact with a "document-object-model" using a web browser which C++ is typically compiled into native code (or sometimes managed code).  It would be silly to make more than a superficial comparison of the two languages.

What I would like to ask is, "As I learn to write JavaScript code, part of my mind can't help but think of it as being like C code because it looks like C code.  What mistakes am I likely making on account of this?  What useful features of the language am I likely not using?"

**Update:** I edited my question title because it's clear that my old title was ambiguous :-/

Comment: +1 but I have a strong feeling this question is going to be [closed] soon.

Comment: It is a good question, just not sure how to answer it

Comment: C != C++. Which one are you familiar with? The *least* difference that makes is whether answers have to state "OO is very different, there are no classes but prototypes" or "There are objects [...]".

Comment: I've only worked seriously with C++, but I understand it to be a superset of C++; compilers typically translate the C++ into C and compile the resulting C code if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Check out Douglas Crockford's talk at Google about Javascript. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook  One of the things he says is that good developers miss a bunch of things in Javascript, because of the similarity in syntax. He goes through what he things are the big ticket items.

Comment: I miss the compiler. I don't get to see simple syntax errors until I actually try running my code. I also miss type checking. And since the browser is what brings all the code files together into one environment, there is no way to check to see if something was undeclared or just declared in another file, which makes refactoring very difficult.

Comment: Uhm, C++ is not a superset of C++. ;-) But I think you meant C. Anyway, no, C++ is not converted to C before it is compiled.

Comment: @CharlieKilian run your js code through jshint in your build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mainly an issue with writing procedural code in JavaScript. You'll miss out on two big features if you write JavaScript like C :

**Prototypical OOP** and **First class functions**

Prototypical OOP allows you to create new objects and apply many of the OOP patterns of other languages. It's rather different from classical OOP.

A good article on that would be [JavaScript Garden Objects section](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object)

First class functions allow you to pass functions as arguments and this allows you to write functional code. With just this alone you can get close to the power of LISP, ML or Haskell. Again a good article is [JavaScript Garden Functions section](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function).

The reason why these two things are big is because they allow you to use the **OOP paradigm** and the **Functional paradigm**.

Otherwise you will be stuck writing Procedural JavaScript forever.

Comment: Yes, good example!  I learnt about this when I started using the jQuery-UI autocomplete widget.  You can specify your own function to look up autocomplete matches and then call a function that autocomplete passes to your function.  It took me a while to understand, but it is enormously useful and malleable.

Answer (score 7):

There is not nearly enough room here, besides, since there is at least one great source I just post a link:

To learn the REAL (deep conceptional) basics of Javascript watch the videos from Douglas Crockford at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

He's one of the most important people in bringing to light the (until then) hidden great power of the language. Besides, he's a very good presenter even for such a relatively dry topic as a programming language.

However, those videos are not very suitable for beginners in programming, but then the question you raise is not a useful one for them either since any answer requires a deeper understanding and quite a bit of practice as well.

Core Javascript is very RAW. You do things that in other languages happens at compile time, for example, when your JS program is loaded you already execute code which assembles objects, "classes" etc. dynamically - and after that initial loading and execution it can be a COMPLETELY different piece of software. You don't have these two stages in any other (old) language (you can do it in Ruby, similar story, those modern languages share certain features). It is therefore NOT helpful to compare JS and C/C++, especially not when you only look at syntax leven stuff, in which case you'll learn nothing at all. It can provide the illusion of learning, though. WATCH CROCKFORD.

---

**A block scope example** for the discussion in another answer here, since I've no other place to put it now (for convenience wrapped in function "foo"). There is a claim you cannot have block scope in Javascript. Granted, in other languages you use a much more familiar syntax, often just enclosing {} or sometimes BEGIN... END. Anyway, the below delivers EXACTLY block scope. Yes, it uses the "function" keyword, but just because you're not used to it does not change the facts.

```
function foo () {
    var a = 1;

    (function () {
        //THIS IS BLOCK SCOPE
        var a = 2;
        console.log(a);
    })();  //IMPORTANT: the "()" executes it immediately, INLINE

    console.log(a);
};
```

Calling foo():

```
2
1
```

If somebody still says "block scope is impossible (in JS)" they should point out what "block scope" is supposed to have that the above example does not provide, apart from needing some getting used to and being less esthetically pleasing than wrapping code in {} or BEGIN...END.

Comment: @Morre Generically you _can_ refer to it as block scope but your renaming function scope to block scope. `(function () {` and `})();` are not keywords that start a new block and end a new block. Yes you've created new scope, but you've created local scope inside a new function. This new function you created exists but since it's not named you don't have a handle or pointer on it. There is a subtle difference.

Comment: @Morre as a seperate matter. The [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement that's coming in the next version of JavaScript creates _real_ block scope.

Comment: I see there are quite a few Crockford videos in the link.  Which ones would you say are most relevant to my question?

Comment: Nice, my office has the linked videos blocked :-/

Comment: @Raynos As I said in those other comments, I won't discuss naming. YET AGAIN: The claim was "block scope is impossible in JS", and I gave an example that refutes that claim. I'm tired of those attempts to reframe the issue. I know about "let" but thanks, THAT is actually a useful reference in this context for others to take notice.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies: The numbered ones about Javascript. Just watch at home, I would not expect employers to be reasonable :)

Comment: @Morre for arguments sake we can rant about the definition of block scope on [SO chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript).

Comment: @Mörre, thank you very much for the link you've provided! It's a genuine treasure.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say

1. Closures
2. Nameless inline objects
3. Dynamic typing
4. Garbage collection
5. Dynamic arrays and objects

but however someone coming from C may not actually "miss" these features... one could happily use javascript as C (of course losing **a lot** doing so and also creating a true nightmare for fellows programmer that actually know javascript if they have to work on the same project).

Comment: Arrays are not like arrays in any other language, instead they are implemented using objects, and those are hash-based. So you don't gain the usual speedy lookup of array elements through the index. I don't have a good feeling with the above list, pls. DO try Douglas Crockfords videos. Before I found them a few years ago I had thought I knew Javascript pretty well (since the very first release in Netscape) only to find I knew NOTHING at all. Yes, you CAN program it "like C" - in which case you are not using it at all, actually.

Comment: More importantly then "losing **a lot**" is making it difficult for future developers. Writing procedural JavaScript will actually hinder future developers on your project, it's not a personal choice you can make, it's a team choice.

Comment: Explicit garbage collectors exists for C/C++. Take a look at [this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) or [this](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html). Finally you can write GC yourself in C/C++, albeit this is not an easy task ...

Comment: @Raynos: I agree (see edit). It's exactly like working on a C++ program when someone that only really knows C just keeps `memcpy`-ing objects around and uses fixed-length char arrays and `strdup` instead of `std::string`. This is the nightmare in which I'm currently forced living at least part of my life... :-(

Comment: @6502 time to use C++ as a better C then C. Sure you could lever the power of C++ but why fight it on your project. C isn't _that_ bad.

Comment: @Raynos: I agree (I actually love C) ... but that part of the code is indeed already a mix of two languages (bad C and horrid C++); for example classes with fixed-length arrays of chars instead of strings, most of members private (beyond usability - actually `protected` because the author didn't know the difference) and then a jillion of friend global functions. There are functions redeclared locally (instead of including the proper .h). Looping gotos. Code copy'n paste like crazy. Structures named after pets or `AAA`. Believe me that when I say a nightmare I mean a nightmare :-D

Comment: @6502 bin it. Start again. Don't tell management, when your two months into your re-write from scratch let management know you started again.

Answer (score 4):

(**Removed previous example**)

I think the #1 cause of confusion is **lack of block scope in JavaScript**:

Here's an example:

```
if (true) {
    var foo = 7;
}
alert(foo);
```

"7" is alerted. Not an expected result to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Lack of block scope is a big thing. The actual problem here is creating anonymous functions in a loop. Rather then using a closure refactor your code so you don't create functions in a loop.

Comment: There is no lack of block scope! I can use an immediately executed anonymous function INLINE in my code and have exactly block scope. Q is, is it useful - but you CAN. Example: outside-code...; (function(){ ...my-code-block...})(); ...again-outside-block;

Comment: @Morre that's not block scope, that's local function scope. There semantically different. `{ foo() }` is a block and is a valid statement in javascript. It's just generally not used without a `for` or `if` statement

Comment: It is NOT a local function! It is executed INLINE!!! WITH the rest of the code, in SEQUENCE! See the () after the function definition. I DO know what I'm talking about. Yes, you need to write a few more characters than just "{}", 12 more to be exact. Just because the syntax is different does not change the outcome - block scope.

Comment: @Raynos: But isn't the root of the problem lack of block scope? And good point, you really should change this code to create functions outside of the loop. I have seen code like this, however, and seen people confused by it.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker No block scope is indeed a problem, although I would blame that particular bug/example more on the _evil_ of creating functions in loops. @Morre There is still a difference between creating a anonymous fuction / function declaration and blocks. It is a local function it just has no name. There is no block scope, there is only function scope.

Comment: @Raynos. Agreed, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Morre by that argument creating a function pointer in C and then executing that function pointer immediately is block scope. These are not the same at all.

Comment: I put an example into my answer here. What is "block scope"? "In computer programming, scope is an enclosing context where values and expressions are associated." (Wikipedia, but let's not get semi-scientific, it means what most people understand when they hear it). My example delivers to you 100% block scope - in Javascript. Actually, it's not my example, I only learned from others of course.

Comment: @Morre: a "block" is a set of statements wrapped in curly braces (as defined by "JavaScript: the good parts." That's where the confusion is here.

Comment: And "block scope" is what is actually MEANT by the thing and it's what the posted code delivers. Yes, naming causes confusion, but in order to unravel it one just looks at the meaning - et voila... even if someone calles something in {} a "block", the discussion was about "block SCOPE is impossible(!) in Javascript", which is wrong. However you call my example construct, and I sure have not seen it in any actual code so maybe NO ONE finds it esthetically pleasing enough to use it (including myself), IT DOES THE JOB that was claimed to be impossible, 100%.

Comment: @Morre But your overloading the definition of _block_. A block in javascript is `{ console.log(1+1) } { console.log(2+2) }`. That is valid code. I merely disapprove with the term "block scope" because it's too tightly coupled with the non-mutable definition of what a block is in javascript. Your overloading names. Block scope is not possible, your example is creating new scope. new scope is possible, and it's a good thing to do.

Comment: I won't argue terms. It was clearly said "block scope is impossible". Was it or was it not? I give an example. If you have nothing to point to what "block scope" is supposed to do that my example does not I suggest we end it here. I sure will, until you or someone else shows me something wrong with my example, something "block scope" does that my tiny piece of code does not achieve. Until then the original statement remains refuted, case closed.

Comment: BTW, the C# equivalent of the first example will produce the same result: user'll be alerted with the last value of i. So C# programmer would expect it...

Comment: @Dmitry: Good point. I think that example is just causing too much confusion. I went ahead and removed it.

Answer (score 1):

How JS differs from C++:

1. Dynamic Typing
2. Functional Programming (leading to nested functions,scope chains and
   closures)
3. Classless OOP and prototypical inheritance
4. Absence of block scope
5. Interpreted language
6. Scripting language (therefore dependent on the environment)

In fact, I wrote a couple of tutorials on JavaScript that highlights these same points. You can read it on [my blog](https://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/professional-javascript-part-i/)

Comment: I enjoyed your write-up about Javascript you link to.  I wonder if there is a .net array equivalent for the Javascript `Array.join` function...

Answer (score 0):

What I always miss:

```
(s)printf
```

or something very similar (= formatted input/output).

What C developers will probably not use that much (at first): functions (lambdas), unless they were using function pointers heavily in C.

Comment: I/O is not part of the core Javascript specification, but esp. the commonjs project has taken care of that, the most famous project implementing that is node.js. I/O is something very specific (hardware, environment), core Javascript is really just "language core".

Comment: `printf === console.log`

Comment: console is NOT part of "Javascript" but added by some actual piece of software on top. You may or may not have a console object.

Comment: printf is not just printf but the whole spectrum of formatted input/output (sprintf, sscanf, etc.), which is really missing.

Comment: It's not "missing", it was deliberately not included. I/O is very dependent on the environment and should therefore not be part of a languages CORE. In that sense, even in C I/O is part of libraries (e.g. stdlib). It's just that in other instances you are used to include libs when you talk about a language, but in Javascript the ECMA standard is limited to the *actual (core) language*, so there is no one "standard" library associated with "Javascript".

Comment: @SztupY if your missing `sprintf` then that's a different matter, I agree we don't have that in JavaScript.

Comment: Mörre: Seems you misunterstand me. I don't want I/O, I want formatted string reading and writing (like sprintf, scanf or String.Format in c#) It is very valuable, in C it is usually used for a lot of things (like padding numbers, converting to/from base8,16,10, etc.), and you need a lot of workaround in JS to do the same

Comment: @SztupY: Oh I do (understand) and whatever you want is fully "legit" of course, I was pointing out for others the design decision and the difference between JS and other languages, where features that are not actually part of the core language are, unlike in JS, much more "bundled" with the language itself. The desire of Netscape to have it standardized in the chosen context is to "blame" (no harm, just different from what most are used to). Formatting is definitely something that you can do WITH the language, so it's not part OF the (core!) language. Of cause in practice that line is blurry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that I learnt about recently: the `arguments` variable.  This variable can be used within any function to access the arguments passed to the function as an array.

When I first learnt that you could declare a function with x parameters and invoke it with y parameters 
(x!=y), I thought that it was awful.  I thought that doing something like that should generate an error; the result of thinking about the Javascript code as if it were C code.

The `arguments` variable allows you to work with a function that may receive any number of variables.  Consider the following example:

```
function returnCount() {
    var count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        count++;
        alert(arguments[i]);
        }
    return count;
}

var number = returnCount('alpha','bravo','charlie');
alert(number);
```

When `returnCount` is invoked with 'alpha', 'bravo', and 'charlie', it will alert with all three values and then return the number three.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

I found Douglas Crockford to be quite informative.  In addition to the videos mentioned in the previous answer, Crockford has a web site with very good information as well: http://javascript.crockford.com/.

I'd like to add something new I've learnt that C developers are likely to miss: the **small number of primitive data types** and the **strict equality operator (===)**.

Javascript has only **boolean**, **string**, and **number** for it's primitive data types.

Of course, C has boolean and string (C-strings, yada yada yada...), but C has many different types of number primitives: 16-bit integer, 32-bit integer, 32-bit byte float, 48-bit float and so on.  Javascript has only a 64-bit float, the IEEE 754 Double Precision floating point.

Unfortunately, this does weird things with arithmetic so that for example, 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 evaluates to false because of the way floating point arithmetic works.

As for the strict equality operator (===), it works like the normal equality operator, but without type coercion.    That means that 3=="3" evaluates to true, but 3==="3" evaluates to false.

Comment: The excellent reference I got this from: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2009/03/10/when-you-cant-count-on-your-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another snippet (excepted from the following link) of code that gives my C-head a migraine.  It allows you to define custom events for your Javascript code.

http://www.geekdaily.net/2008/04/02/javascript-defining-and-using-custom-events/

```
var CustomEvent = function() {
    //name of the event
    this.eventName = arguments[0];
    var mEventName = this.eventName;

    //function to call on event fire
    var eventAction = null;

    //subscribe a function to the event
    this.subscribe = function(fn) {
        eventAction = fn;
    };

    //fire the event
    this.fire = function(sender, eventArgs) {
        this.eventName = eventName2;
        if(eventAction != null) {
            eventAction(sender, eventArgs);
        }
        else {
            alert('There was no function subscribed to the ' + mEventName + ' event!');
        }
    };
};
```